# display category name with links in search page

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

how do you display category title and their respective links and contents.

I have my codes and the contents on posts are working but not on the category's title/links

something link this:

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: Search
*/
?>


<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php 
    echo '<a href="'. get_category_link($current_cat_id). '>'. the_category(' ').'</a> '; ?>                    
    the_title();
   the_excerpt();    
<?php endwhile; ?>


    <?php else : ?>

        <h2>No posts found.</h2>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_the_category_list`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list):

```
$categories_list = get_the_category_list( ', ' );
if( $categories_list ) echo $categories_list;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did solved it by using this code

```
<?php  echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . the_category(" ").'</a> '; ?>
```